# Generating hexagon (tessellation) fishnet inside hexagon (tesellation) fishnet using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-grid, tesselation

I'd like to create a fishnet or hexagons inside a subset area of hexagons? Basically I want a large cell size for my rural area and a small cell size for the urban area. This is the tool I've used to create the fishnet:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/generatetesellation.htm

Comment: Don't you just change the size parameter in that tool?

Comment: Hexagons can be tessellated by triangles (six per hex), but not by hexagons.

Comment: @Vince oi. That is correct, I do feel a touch stupid now. To your answer, can you ensure that the triangles match the boundary of the hex?

Comment: I had code that made the triangles first, with the hexagon-id as an attribute for dissolve, but you just need to find the opposite transect midpoint to determine the common triangle point.